# I need to find a way to paste a function along with a column name in formula editor

Tags: selenium

In my web application i need to paste a function along with a column name like lowercase([FirstName]) where lowercase is the function and [FirstName] is the column. If i send the value through sendKeys this is not working as our application has a limitation that if anyone is writing 'lowercase([FirstName])' by manual typing then this would not work. So how can i mimic the paste operation on this.Also i am wworking with the ANT framework where we are maintaining the CSVs for the element operations.

I have already tried sendKeys which is not working as i am getting "Expression is Invalid" message on clicking the validate button. This is because of the Application's limitation. Also writing a javascript will mimic the same operation of sending the keyword as individual letters and not pasting the whole keyword. So can anybody suggest any other way of copy-pasting a value in this type of framework?

Comment: could you share the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Please try it with following action, if it won't work please try it with removing the `click()` method:

```
Actions action = new Action(driver);

action.moveToElement(firstNameElement).click().sendKeys(firstNameElement, lowercase([FirstName])).build().perform();
```